# Как убрать увеличение экрана на IPhone при нажатии на select (или input) без увеличения размера шрифта?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, scss

Знаю про решение с увеличением шрифта элементов формы

```css
 @media (max-width: 580px) {
  input, select {
    font-size: 16px;
  }
}
```

Но хотелось быть узнать есть ли еще какие-нибудь решения

Answer (score 0):

Для iphone 9 и ниже (для 10 уже не работает) можно было добавить `user-scalable=0` у `viewport`

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0"/>
```

Можно, как пример, этот `viewport` менять js'ом, что-то типа этого:

```
if (/iPhone/.test(navigator.userAgent) && !window.MSStream)
{
    $(document).on("focus", "input, textarea, select", function()
    {
        $('meta[name=viewport]').remove();
        $('head').append('<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0">');
    });

    $(document).on("blur", "input, textarea, select", function()
    {
        $('meta[name=viewport]').remove();
        $('head').append('<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Есть два варианта:

**1.** Шрифт не менее 16px

**2.** Запрет масштабирования `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">`

Но я бы не рекомендовал отключать масштабирование. Это неправильное решение. Лучше через CSS исправить эту проблему:

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 0) {
select:focus, textarea:focus, input:focus {
        font-size: 16px;
    }
}
```